# Slow download speeds on MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, networking, speed

Just as the title says, I am getting *very* low download speeds on my MacBook Pro.

I did a speed test at speedtest.net, and am getting 7 MbPS down, .5 up. However, I can only seem to get 270 **KB** PS max (averaging 100 K), whether on my school's network or on my home network, wired or wireless.

I am on Mac OS X 10.5.8, with Google Chrome. My ethernet settings (under System Preferences -> Network -> Ethernet Connection -> Advanced -> Ethernet) are set to "Configure Automatically", "Speed: 100TX", "Duplex: full-duplex, flow-control", and "MTU: Standard (1500)".

As far as I can tell, there are no throttles or anything between here and the ISP, so...

Any ideas on why I'm getting such low download speeds?